# How to add monitoring in my Elastic Beanstalk CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have prepared an Elastic Beanstalk CloudFormation template.

```
Resources:
  BeanStalkApplciation:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Condition: conCreateBeanStalkApplication
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref BeanStalkApplciationName
      Description: PBKMSService Beanstalk applciation
  BeanstalkEnvironmet:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      TemplateName: !If
        - conDontUseConfigTemplate
        - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
        - !Ref BeanStalkConfigTemplateName
      EnvironmentName: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Ref BeanStalkApplciationName
          - !Ref BeanStalkEnvironment
      Description: Service Beanstalk Environment
      ApplicationName: !Ref BeanStalkApplciationName
      SolutionStackName: !Ref BeanStalkSolutionStackName
      Tier:
        Name: WebServer
        Type: Standard
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment'
          OptionName: ServiceRole
          Value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment'
          OptionName: ServiceRole
          Value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: InstanceType
          Value: !Ref EC2InstanceType
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg'
          OptionName: Availability Zones
          Value: Any 2
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg'
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: !Ref AutoscalingMinSize
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:asg'
          OptionName: MaxSize
          Value: !Ref AutoscalingMaxSize
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: MeasureName
          Value: RequestCount
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: Statistic
          Value: Sum
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: Unit
          Value: Count/Second
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: Period
          Value: 5
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: BreachDuration
          Value: 5
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: UpperThreshold
          Value: 100
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: UpperBreachScaleIncrement
          Value: 1
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: LowerThreshold
          Value: 50
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:trigger'
          OptionName: LowerBreachScaleIncrement
          Value: -1
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate'
          OptionName: RollingUpdateEnabled
          Value: 'true'
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate'
          OptionName: RollingUpdateType
          Value: Health
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption'
          OptionName: EBLogGroup
          Value: !Ref CloudwatchLogGroup
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value: !Ref EC2SecGroupForBeanStalk
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:loadbalancer'
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value: !Ref ELBSecGroupForBeanStalk
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value: !Ref KeyPairForEc2Instances
        - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
          OptionName: VPCId
          Value: !Ref VpcId
        - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
          OptionName: Subnets
          Value: !Join
            - ','
            - !Ref BeanStalkApplcitionSubnets
        - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
          OptionName: ELBSubnets
          Value: !Join
            - ','
            - !Ref BeanStalkELBSubnets
        - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
          OptionName: AssociatePublicIpAddress
          Value: !Ref AssignPublicIPToEC2
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:loadbalancer'
          OptionName: CrossZone
          Value: 'true'
        - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
          OptionName: ELBScheme
          Value: !If
            - conIsInternalApplcation
            - 'internal'
            - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443'
          OptionName: ListenerEnabled
          Value: !If
            - conIsInternalApplcation
            - false
            - true
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443'
          OptionName: SSLCertificateId
          Value: !If
            - conIsInternalApplcation
            - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
            - !Ref SSLCertificateARN
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443'
          OptionName: ListenerProtocol
          Value: HTTPS
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443'
          OptionName: InstancePort
          Value: '80'
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:443'
          OptionName: InstanceProtocol
          Value: HTTP
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener'
          OptionName: ListenerEnabled
          Value: !If
            - conIsInternalApplcation
            - true
            - false
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:80'
          OptionName: ListenerEnabled
          Value: !If
            - conIsInternalApplcation
            - true
            - false
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:80'
          OptionName: ListenerProtocol
          Value: HTTP
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:80'
          OptionName: InstancePort
          Value: '80'
        - Namespace: 'aws:elb:listener:80'
          OptionName: InstanceProtocol
          Value: HTTP
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_APP_NAME
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsApplciationName
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: MAGENT_APPD_APP_NAME
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsMachineAgentApplciationName
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_TIER_NAME
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsTierName
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_ACCT_NAME
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsAgentAccountName
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_CONT_HOST
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsControllerHostName
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_CONT_PORT
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsControllerPort
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_CONT_SSL_ENABLED
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsControllerSslEnabled
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: APPD_ACCESS_KEY
          Value: !Ref envAppdynamicsAgentAccountAccessKey
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: SPLUNK_SERVER_HOST
          Value: !Ref envSplunkServerHost
```

I want to add monitoring feature to it. I don't find any ref/examples regarding the same.

After you create Elastic Beanstalk, you go to monitoring. I want to add a couple of graphs using CloudFormation. Below is the screenshot of monitoring UI.

[image]

I have referred this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aeb-metricscollected.html but again it is not clear. How can I get the instanceid of a beanstalk resource? Can we even do that using CloudFormation?

Comment: What exactly do you want to monitor?

Comment: I think you'll need to expand on your question to get a useful reply.  I doubt people will click through the link and read the instructions that you refer to -- bring the relevant steps and what you have done into a more detailed question

Comment: Thanks for replying . expanded my question.